# Is it possible to commit only part of the SQLs when jdbc autocommit is false

Tags: jdbc, autocommit

Let's say in a big old java app, the autocommit of JDBC is set to false.
In the middle of on existing transaction, I add some new logic and execute new sql statement, for example,

```
execute sql statement1
execute sql statement2
......
              <---my new sql statementA
......
execute sql statementn
```

The question is, I don't want to break the old transaction control(it has its own COMMITs and ROLLBACKs), I need to only commit the new sql statementA, is it possible?

Comment: Only if you use a separate connection.

Comment: Whatever you are adding is inserting data that is child of or dependent on data that is getting inserted in old sql code. i.e. why you want to do this?

Comment: It depends on the database you're using. For example, in Oracle you can use an autonomous transaction to do something like what you're proposing here. Please add the appropriate database tag(s) and perhaps you'll get an answer. Thanks.